# Identifying Bottom Bracket on Merida Scultura 7000e

Tags: shimano, bottom-bracket

I've just purchased a Merida Scultura 7000e frameset (unsure what year model). How do I go about identifying what bottom bracket standard it uses so that I can purchase one.

Inner Diameter of the bottom bracket hole is 37mm.
Depth of bottom bracket hole is about 9.5mm.

Trying to fit Shimano 105 5800 cranks on there (believe that they are cranks with a 24mm axle)

Comment: Can you post some photos? Is the BB shell threaded? If threaded, 99% it's an english threaded 68mm shell. SM-BBR600 and alike should work.

Comment: Hi, It's definitely not threaded.

Comment: 37mm matches ID of BB90, but I wasn't able to find any mention of BB90 on Scultura, only BB386 and PF86. What's the shell width?

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation provided on Merida's website, **the bottom bracket standard is PF86**.

[Source](https://www.merida-bikes.com/en/bike/113/scultura-disc-7000-e)

Comment: Hi, the thing is that I'm not sure what year the frame is from as I have purchased it second hand. It is a rim brake model as well, so there is a possibility that the frame has been completely reworked, and didn't previously use the PF86 standard.

Comment: @M.Choy  the 7000e lineup has always utilized the PF86 standard. It is very unlikely that another standard was utilized on their older frames.

Comment: Strange, it looks identical to images of bb90/bb95 online

Comment: thanks for the comment, took it to LBS and they said that the cups have already been installed. Just need to get the bearings.